# QTabWidget size depending on current Tab

Tags: c++, qt, tabs, size, qtabwidget

I've a `QTabWidget`, which contains widgets of different heights (their widths are fixed), however, the default implementation of`QTabWidget` selects the biggest widget's height as own height.

What I would like to know if there's a (possible fast) way to change the size of `QTabWidget` depending on its current tab, to save space when smaller tabs are shown.

Comment: The `QTabWidget` won't select the biggest widget's height as its own height unless you use layout on the `QTabWidget`. Therefore, if you want to change the size of `QTabWidget` manually, remove the layout and call `QTabWidget::resize` according to the `currentChanged` signal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the size policy of the widget that is displayed to `QSizePolicy::Preferred` and the other ones to `QSizePolicy::Ignored`. After that call `adjustSize` to update the sizes. For example you can connect the `currentChanged` signal of the `QTabWidget` to a slot :

```
connect(ui->tabWidget,SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)),this, SLOT(updateSizes(int)));
```

And set size policies and adjust sizes accordingly in the slot :

```
void MainWindow::updateSizes(int index)
{
    for(int i=0;i<ui->tabWidget->count();i++)
        if(i!=index)
            ui->tabWidget->widget(i)->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);

    ui->tabWidget->widget(index)->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    ui->tabWidget->widget(index)->resize(ui->tabWidget->widget(index)->minimumSizeHint());
    ui->tabWidget->widget(index)->adjustSize();
    resize(minimumSizeHint());
    adjustSize();
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Even though, I want to know why the `adjustSize` calls are neccesary. I've commented both of them and your solution does still work fine.

Comment: @Peregring-lk : the last two lines resize the main window itself. You might want to avoid it, depending on your application. For example, if you set the rest of the widgets to expand into the space just made available, it's not so nice if the window resizes itself instead.

Answer (score 1):

OK so this question was already has an accepted answer, but I decided to share my solution, which works remarkably well. It is a small code snippet based on Nejat's answer, and it will work for `QTabWidget` and `QStackedWidget`.

```
template <typename T>
void pack(T *stacked)
{
    for(int i=0; i<stacked->count(); i++) {
        stacked->widget(i)->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
    }
    QWidget *widget=stacked->currentWidget();
    widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    widget->resize(widget->minimumSizeHint());
    widget->adjustSize();
    stacked->resize(stacked->minimumSizeHint());
    stacked->adjustSize();
}
```

NOTE: I used Minimum instead of Preferred to make it take up as small size as possible. Also, this solution expects the currently selected widget to already be set.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
void adjust_minimum_size(QTabWidget* pages)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pages->count(); i++) {
        pages->widget(i)->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
    }
    pages->currentWidget()->resize(1, 1);
    pages->currentWidget()->adjustSize();
    pages->resize(1, 1);
    pages->adjustSize();
    pages->window()->resize(1, 1);
    pages->window()->adjustSize();
    pages->currentWidget()->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    pages->currentWidget()->resize(pages->currentWidget()->minimumSizeHint());
    pages->currentWidget()->adjustSize();
    pages->resize(pages->minimumSizeHint());
    pages->adjustSize();
    pages->window()->resize(pages->window()->minimumSizeHint());
    pages->window()->adjustSize();
}
```